# dplyr: Create a new column with a complex operation using mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create a new data frame (`new.df`) using an original (`df`) but with a new column (`Age`) using a complex operation with `mutate` function in `dplyr` package. My steps are:

```
# Artificial dataframe
IDtest<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Class<-c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,3)
Day<-c(0,47,76,100,150,173,0,47,76,0,47,76,100)
Area<-c(0.45,0.85,1.50,1.53,1.98,5.2,
         0.36,0.58,1.2,
         0.85,1.36,2.26,3.59)
df<-data.frame(cbind(IDtest, Class, Day, Area))
str(df)

#Split each IDtest
df[df[,1]==1,]
#  IDtest Class Day Area
#1      1     1   0 0.45
#2      1     1  47 0.85
#3      1     2  76 1.50
#4      1     2 100 1.53
#5      1     2 150 1.98
#6      1     3 173 5.20
```

Inside each `IDtest`:

1. Last `Area` inside each `Class` minus a factor (If the Area < 1 = 0; < 2.9 = 1; < 8.9 = 3; < 24.9 = 9; > 25 = 25); and
2. Than 1) divided by make subtraction between last and first `Area` and divided by `Day` inside each `Class`
3. Than 1) and 2) sum `Day` inside each `Class` minus last `Day`. Finally sum of all divided by 365 and create a new column `Age`

```
#For Class 1
(0.85-0)/((0.85-0.45)/47) + (47 - 0) 

#For Class 2
(1.98-1)/((1.98-0.85)/150) + (157 - 47)

#For Class 3
(5.20-3)/((5.2-1.98)/173) + (173 - 150)

#Final 
Age<-((0.85-0)/((0.85-0.45)/47) + (47 - 0) +
(1.98-1)/((1.98-0.85)/150) + (157 - 47) + 
(5.20-3)/((5.2-1.98)/173) + (173 - 150))/365
Age
#[1] 1.44702

# Desirable output
new.df
#  IDtest Class Day Area Age
#1      1     1   0 0.45 1.44702
#2      1     1  47 0.85 1.44702
#3      1     2  76 1.50 1.44702
#4      1     2 100 1.53 1.44702
#5      1     2 150 1.98 1.44702
#6      1     3 173 5.20 1.44702
```

Please any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite tricky, so I have made all steps separatedly, to make you easier detecting any possible missunderstanding.
Is it possible that a mistake exists in this line of yours?

```
(1.98-1)/((1.98-0.85)/150) + (157 - 47) # 157? wouldn't it be 150?
```

That said, my results for Class 1 are the same as yours, but please be careful with Class 2 and 3, because I'm not sure of properly understanding the second and third steps, I'm not absolutely sure about your use of "last" (i.e. "last" in the Class or the "previous" Class).

In the second step I use "last" in the Class and in third one I use a for loop to use "the previous". I think you can addapt the idea

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(IDtest, Class) %>%
    mutate(
      DayOrder = row_number() 
    )

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(step1a = Area[max(DayOrder)], # I divide step1 in several steps to make it clearer
     minus =  # what you want to substract
       case_when(
         step1a < 1 ~ 0,
         step1a < 2.9 ~ 1,
         step1a < 8.9 ~ 3,
         step1a < 24.9 ~ 9,
         step1a > 25 ~ 25
       ),
     step1done = step1a - minus, 
     step2a = Area[max(DayOrder)] - Area[min(DayOrder)], # "Last" inside the same Class (as it is inside mutate, which is under group_by)
     step2b = Day[max(DayOrder)],
     step2done = step2a / step2b,
     step1by2 = step1done / step2done
     )


df2$step3 <- NA 
for (i in 1:max(df2$Class)){
  if(i == 1){
     df2$step3[Class == i] <- max(df2$Day[df2$Class == i]) - 0 # quite silly
     }else{
     df2$step3[Class == i] <- max(df2$Day[df2$Class == i]) - max(df2$Day[df2$Class == i - 1]) # "Last" as the "previous" Class, not inside the same Class
 }}


df2 %>%
  mutate(
    step3done = step1by2 + step3,
    Age = step3done / 365 # Do you want "age" as a unique value?? not a value for each person? This case I would do this outside mutate and add as a new column
  )
```

If I have misunderstood you, I hope you can at least take some ideas!

Comment: Miguel, your code help so much!!! I have just a little problem now in max(df2$Day[df2$Class == i - 1] because of the must of time the Class in my dataset increase non-continuously. Class changes the value 1 for 4. In this case, your code gives me -Inf values, because is necessary to use the last Class values (1) and not 3 that don't exist. You see any simple modification here?

Comment: I think I don't fully undestand you. 
So "Class" is somehow a group of people and instead of numeric it could be "A", "B", "C"... But also you need to take in account "last Day" (of the previous Class). 
If you have few categories of "Class", you could use specific if(){}else{} inside the for loop. 
For instance, if the previous Class to 4 is 2, you could do

Comment: if the previous Class to 4 is 2, you could do something like: 
if(i == 4){... - max(df2$Day[df2$Class == 2])} 

Or without the for loop:
df2$step3[Class == 4] <- ... - max(df2$Day[df2$Class == 2])

Comment: Thank Miguel!! Help so much.